# elementary OS doesn't detect my partitions

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

READ THIS FIRST : [Elementary OS Setup doesn't detect my partitions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/elementary-os-setup-doesnt-detect-my-partitions) **I am author of this, don't mark as duplicate, because i didn't registered there, and deleted all cookies so i was must to question again.**

I am trying to install the elementary OS alongside Windows (Dual-booting). I have few NTFS partitions, with 500GB Total. But Installation Setup say that my hard drive is empty drive without partitions. It doesn't detect any partitions.

But when i try to exit the setup and get to file explorer, all partitions are showed with their data. But only SETUP doesn't detect it.

1. Only 500 GB Empty Drive. Should be 500 GB Drive with much of
   partitions and 60 GB of unallocated space.
2. File Explorer can see all partitions in drive, but Setup doesn't.

Why this even doesn't work?
Something messed up in Setup?
Also my installation media is USB.
[image: Screenshot of Disk Managament]
The installation shows up only empty 500 GB Drive.
But File Explorer can read it at all.

Comment: Please redpond to @Tim question there. Also can you post screenshot of your partition table in windows?

Comment: Again, can you post a screenshot of either the setup partition manager or from `gparted`?

Comment: Can you post partition setup screenshot as well

Comment: Is an issue that happens when you resize or modify ntfs partitions using the native patition tool in windows. The only solution i know is creating a new partition table but it destroy all data, equivalent to format all partitions